# WP Speed of Light - how to exclude single image from being lazy-loaded

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, lazy-loading

trying to achieve better performance for our WooCommerce-shop. We installed "WP-Speed of light", which actually gives us good results. The problem is, the Images inside our Header are being lazy-loaded. Looks horrible, how they are showing up one after each other (even though they've been cached). I found the WPSoL Settings to exlude URL's from being lazy-loaded. This only works for hole pages I believe, not for single images. As my Header is on every page, excluding the hole page (all pages), is not an option. Is there somebody who can point me out, how to exclude single image-URL's? Is it even possible? If not, any Plugin-Recommendation where I can do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest update:

```
  2.4.5 Add : Implement lazyloading exclusion by id or class selector
```

This can easily be done, by using the same field, as if you would like to exclude page-URL's. This can be found in your Wordpress-Backend. Go to "WP-Speed of light/Speed optimization" Just type identifiers (class or id) and URL's using "Lazy-Loading exclusion"-field as follows:

`class1
class2
id1
https://example.com/page`

Just use next line for seperation. No "#" for id's or "." for classes needed.

As they are currently facing some update-issues, you may need to update WP-SoL-Addon Version manually. This can be done by making a backup, downloading latest addon-version on https://joomunited.com/my-account and copying it to the appropiate location of your webspace.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enter the full URL of the image you want to exclude

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/.../logo.png
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Doesn't seem to work though. Thanks

Comment: Selecting single images doesn't seem to work. My last approach was, having images in separate folder and use star-notation, like this: `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/images/header/*`. According to manual WPSoL supports star-notation, but no success. Thanks!

Comment: 2.4.5 -> Add : Implement lazyloading exclusion by id or class selector. Still doesn't seem to work for me. Can't just type selector where you usually would exclude pages. Also can't find a new section or anything. Do they mean, I give them a certain class-name? How is this done?